# Spring webflux: Race of parallel calls and cancel/return when one of the responses has data

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I have three parallel calls to three different endpoints, and only one of them is going to return the data that I like to process (the response will have data only for enpoint-1, enpoint-2 or endpoint-3).
If one of this calls return data, I'd like to return this data immediately and forget about the other calls...¿How can I achieve this with Spring Webflux?

I have the three calls with:

```
Mono<MyResponse> result = client.post()
  .uri('uri')
  .body(Mono.just(request), MyRequest.class)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
```

Added to a Mono list

```
 List<Mono<MyResponse>> calls
```

And I have a merge of all the responses and look for the first item:

```
Flux.merge(calls).toStream().forEach(response -> myResponseList.addAll(response));
```

But I would like to return the data as soon as any of the calls return something different than null and not wait for the 'merge' to be completed.

Thanks!

Comment: The code above should work. Flux.merge(calls) should return the data as soon as response from any of the monos is available and pass it to the forEach method. Maybe i don't understand what is that you are trying to accomplish. I run the simple example: `Mono<Long> delay1 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000));`
        Mono<Long> delay2 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(2000));
        List<Mono<Long>> listOfMonos = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfMonos.add(delay1);
        listOfMonos.add(delay2);
        Flux.merge(listOfMonos).toStream().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Thanks piotr, I want to check the reponses as they come in and return if the response is not null. So what I have to do is to check in the foreach if the response is not null and ¿then break the foreach? or ¿maybe something like a filter.findFirst() to return when some data is found?

Comment: I think in that case this is your best option: `Long aLong = Flux.merge(listOfMonos).filter((t) -> t != null).toStream().findFirst().get();`

Answer (score 0):

You could take only the first element of your flux

```
 Flux.merge(calls).take(1)
```

You get new Flux with only first element and it completes after producing it.

Comment: I think this not meet the original criteria. As the null check on the response is missing. The code you proposed simply return whatever comes back first.

Comment: Why don't filter webclient retrieve result to return emty if response is null?